# Preventing tasks from being deleted

Tags: apex

There’ve been cases when particular task is deleted by someone by mistake (no data would be available in these cases about who deleted it, but the result is – lack of task). Is there a way to prevent a tasks from being deleted or somehow to create a restriction so that no task could be deleted after creation?

Regards,

Dilyan

Answer (score 3):

There are two option for that.

1. You can remove delete permission from Profile so that no one can delete the task except administrator.
2. If you want to include system administrator in that list you can write a before delete trigger from where you will throw an exception and SFDC will roll back transaction.

You can use following code for your reference:

```
Trigger PreventDelete on Task (before delete)
{

    for(Task tsk : Trigger.old)
    {
      tsk.addError('Deletion of task is disabled');
    }
 }
```

Comment: I suggest keeping the scope of such a trigger narrow e.g. limiting it to only certain SObjectType parents of particular profiles. Remember that over time extra apps may be added and extra users may be added and blocking deletion of Tasks for those apps or people may well be a bad thing.

Comment: I agree with you Keith.